# Best method for scaling a vector to desired length

Tags: c++, floating-point, geometry, computational-geometry

The question is about the most robust and the fastest implementation about this rather basic operation:

Given a vector (X,Y) compute the collinear vector of the given length desiredLength. There are at least two methods for that:

One. Find the length of (X,Y) and rescale accordingly:

```
double currentLength = sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
if(currentLength == 0) { /* Aye, Caramba! */ }
double factor = desiredLength / currentLength;
X *= factor;
Y *= factor;
```

Two. Find the direction of (X,Y) and form a vector of desiredLength in that direction:

```
if(X == 0 && Y == 0) { /* Aye, Caramba! */ }
double angle = atan2(Y, X);
X = desiredLength * cos(angle);
Y = desiredLength * sin(angle);
```

Which method would be preferable for developing robust app, better numerical stability, faster execution, etc.?

Comment: The first one won't explode if the vector is vertical, and is also scalable to more dimensions (if that's relevant to you). If speed's a concern then you'll have to measure it; but three complicated functions are likely to be slower than one.

Comment: atan2 doesn't explode when y is 0, it just returns pi/2 or -pi/2, depending on the sign of x. Other than that - yes, all the answers in favour of the 1st method make sense. It could even be slightly improved by using hypot(x,y) instead of sqrt(x*x+y*y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one right answer, since it will depend on the implementation.
However: on any reasonable modern implementation, the four basic
operations and `sqrt` will be exact to the last binary digit.  From a
quality of implementation point of view, one would hope that the same
thing would be true for all of the functions in `math.h`, but it's less
certain.  On a machine with IEEE arithmetic (Windows and the mainstream
Unix platforms), the four operations *and* `sqrt` will be implemented in
hardware, where as the trigonomic operations will generally require a
software implementation, often requiring tens of more basic operations.
Although some floating point processors do support them directly, at
least over limited ranges, even then, they are often a magnitude slower
than the four basic operations.

All of which speaks in favor of your first implementation, at least with
regards to speed (and probably with regards to numeric stability as
well).

Comment: There is no point in hoping that all of the functions in `math.h` are correctly rounded; nobody has done it yet with any fixed-precision (or known-bounded run time) implementation. [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/) is working on it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In general, I would hope that the results would be within 1LSB of the correctly rounded results (which means about 1.5LSB with regards to the exact results).  Although I can remember a case where the trig functions were only exact to about 6 decimal digits (in double precision!).  `sqrt` is an exception, where you can (and should) expect the precise rounded result (.5LSB precision).

Answer (score 2):

Thu shalt better use `hypot(x,y)` rather than `sqrt(x*x+y*y)` because a reasonnable implementation of hypot can save you from underflow/overflow conditions.

Examples: `hypot(1.0e300,1.0e300)` or `hypot(1.0e-300,1.0e-300)`

Then evaluating x/hypot(x,y) is safe, even in case of gradual underflow (denormalized numbers) like x=1.0e-320, y=0, while evaluating desiredLength/hypot(x,y) might well overflow.

So I would write

```
double h  = hypot(x,y);
double xd = desiredLength*(x/h);
double yd = desiredLength*(y/h);
```

You'll get some division by zero exception and nan results if both x,y are zero, so don't bother handling it in a if.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect method one to be better At least on the performance front as doing sqrt + 2 multiplications should be cheaper than 3 trig operations.
I would guess it is also better (or not worse) on the other fronts as well since it involves one approximation (sqrt) instead of 2 (per axis). The sqrt approximation is also "shared" by both x and y.